# Target "Any CPU" with "Prefer 32-bit" disabled gets compiled with 32-bit preference anyway

Tags: c#, .net, corflags

I set my target to "Any CPU" with "Prefer 32-bit" disabled.

[image]

I wondered why my process is still running as 32-bit on a 64-bit system, so I checked
CorFlags. It confirms, that my executable gets compiled with 32BITPREF enabled.

[image]

What would cause this?

Comment: Did you change that for debug and release?

Comment: @GSerg I have it disabled for both Debug and Release config if that is what you mean. I double checked and compiled exactly what you are seeing in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the project file to see what `<Prefer32Bit>` was actually set to, but oddly it wasn't explicitly specified at all.

So VS obviously defaults to `<Prefer32Bit>` to `true`if the tag isn't present, which is consistent with respect to *[What AnyCPU Really Means As Of .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11](https://dzone.com/articles/what-anycpu-really-means-net)*:

> In .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 11 the cheese has been moved. The
> default for most .NET projects is again AnyCPU, but there is more than
> one meaning to AnyCPU now. **There is an additional sub-type of AnyCPU,
> “Any CPU 32-bit preferred”, which is the new default**...

Adding `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` manually solved the issue.

No idea why the tag was missing in the first place. Maybe the project was updated from a pre .Net Framework 4.5 version and VS missed to add when performing the project update?

But not setting the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox when the tag is missing seems to be an oversight from VS.